# Rails class inheritance, Mongoid fails to return data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, mongoid

With these models:

models/asset.rb

```
class Asset < Entity
     include Mongoid::Document
end
```

models/assets/text.rb

```
module Assets
    class Text < Asset
        include Mongoid::Document
        store_in collection: "#{tenant_uuid}_contents"
    end
end
```

the Rails console returns:

> > Entity.all.entries
> >
> > MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=dbname collection=**entities** selector={} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.3572ms)
> >     []
> >
> > Asset.all.entries
> >
> > MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=dbname collection=**2b66d7a9-8cb5-4802-838a-f1f58869bbf5_contents** selector={"$query"=>{"_type"=>{"$in"=>["Asset"]}}, "$orderby"=>{"_id"=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.9501ms)
> >     []

But if I then do Entity.all.entries again (ie. after Asset.all.entries) I get a different response:

> > Entity.all.entries
> >
> > MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=dbname collection=**2b66d7a9-8cb5-4802-838a-f1f58869bbf5_contents** selector={} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (3.2308ms)
> >
> > MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 **GET_MORE** .... **and all documents are returned here**

If I remove the fact that Asset inherits from Entity, then

```
Assets.all.entries
```

always works the first time and returns all documents.

So there is something I am not understanding about the inheritance chain here. Or the fact that Entity is not stored in the contents collection - it is like an 'abstract' class (the Entity class is inherited by other objects which are stored in their own respective collections).

So is the problem here that Mongoid cannot support such an inheritance structure? Do we HAVE to store Entity in the same collection as its children?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please supply your model definition for Entity.

Comment: @GaryMurakami sorry, but I have the answer now, with links to the same problem that describe it better than I have :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is a pretty well know "issue". And actually it is by design.

Here are [two](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1133#issuecomment-1764355) [notes](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1133#issuecomment-1767252) from the author:

> Mongoid's inheritance functions as single collection inheritance and
>   thus all models in the inheritance chain would store in the same
>   collection - if it changes on one it changes on all.

Similar case [here](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2857). And a suggestion on how to tackle this, again from the author, is to [mixin modules rather than inheritance](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2995#issuecomment-17007697):

> If you want to have common functionality between models, but have them
>   store in different collections you should be using modules, not
>   inheritance.

HTH!

Comment: thanks so much for that information, your 'HTH' does indeed :)

Comment: These links are now unfortunately no longer valid 